# What's could be the right test case for evaluating assignment operators performance vs concrete operations?

Tags: java, performance, operators

Simply I am trying to figure out what is the fast way to assign a value like

```
somevar+=1;
```

or

```
somevar=somevar+1;
```

time ago in situations with text instead of integers I encountered some performance decrease using `text+="sometext"` instead of `text.append("sometext")` or `text=text+"sometext"`, the problem is that I did not find anymore the source code where I annotated my considerations. So theoretically what's the fastest way?

The code background is set into a fast loop, nearly real time.

Answer (score 4):

If you have something like this:

```
Collection<String> strings = ...;
String all = "";
for (String s : strings) all += s;
```

... then it's equivalent to:

```
Collection<String> strings = ...;
String all = "";
for (String s : strings) all = new StringBuilder(all).append(s).toString();
```

Each loops creates a new `StringBuilder` which is essentially a copy of `all`, appends a copy of `s` to it, and then copies the result of the concatenation to a new `String`. Obviously, using a single StringBuilder saves a lot of unnecessary allocations:

```
Collection<String> strings = ...;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : strings) sb.append(s);
String all = sb.toString();
```

As for `x += y` versus `x = x + y`, they compile to the same thing.

```
class Concat {

        public String concat1(String a, String b) {
                a += b;
                return a;
        }

        public String concat2(String a, String b) {
                a = a + b;
                return a;
        }

}
```

Compile it with `javac`, and then disassemble it with `javap`:

```
$ javap -c Concat
Compiled from "Concat.java"
class Concat extends java.lang.Object{
Concat();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public java.lang.String concat1(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   7:   aload_1
   8:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   11:  aload_2
   12:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   15:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   18:  astore_1
   19:  aload_1
   20:  areturn

public java.lang.String concat2(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   7:   aload_1
   8:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   11:  aload_2
   12:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   15:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   18:  astore_1
   19:  aload_1
   20:  areturn

}
```

Personally, I'd favor `+=` because with it, you make a clearer statement of intent - "I want to add the content of `b` to `a`". Any variations in performance between the two forms are with a 100% certainty the result of something outside of your code (e.g., GC pauses, random cache misses or something like it).

Bad compilers might also have a slightly easier time to optimize the `+=` form (which is irrelevant to you, since even if `javac` would be crappy, HotSpot sure isn't).

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable. Hence, concatenating 2 Strings causes a new String object to be created. Using **StringBuilder** will gain you a lot of performance.

However, primitive numeric types are not immutable and not heap allocated. Whatever you do with them tends to be really fast no matter what :)

Comment: Concatenating 2 `String` s with `+` is really expensive and should be avoided, especially in loops. Make sure to use primitive types such as `int` instead of `Integer` wherever you can.

Comment: @f1sh: Actually, string concatenation with `+` is in many cases not more expensive than `StringBuilder`. I'm sure *you* know this but it's always worth pointing out for all premature optimizers out there: The main reason for using `StringBuilder` instead of `+` is if you're doing non-one-liners to build up a string for some reason, like when in a loop or if the code is really long. Saying `new StringBuilder("Feces occurred: (").append(errMsg).append(", code = ").append(errCode).append(")").toString()` is in no way faster than doing the same thing with `+`, just far less readable.

Answer (score 1):

String 'arithmetics' internal are rather complicated - just because they happen quite often and the compilers tries to optimize whereever it can.

First of all, `append("something")` is not a `String` method. It is a method from the `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` class.

The other expressions are quite equivalent. I'm pretty sure one can't look at the pattern and decide that one is faster in general.

In General and because Strings are immutable, a concatenation will create a new String for each String literal, a new String for each intermediate result and one new String for the result. So this

```
String s = "one" + "two" + "three";
```

will require five String objects ("one", "two", "three", "onetwo", "onwtwothree").

The first compiler optimization is 'interning' the literals. In short: "one", "two" and "three" are not created but reused.

A second compiler optimization is replacing the String addition by StringBuilder operation (if it makes sense). So the concatenation could be replaced by

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("one");
sb.append("two");
sb.append("three");
String s = sb.toString();
```

(just to illustrate - a real compiler might not use the strategy for this example code, it might concatenate the the literals during compilation already...)